# How to tell phpunit to stop on failure

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm running a large suite of phpunit tests, and I'd like see which test failed as soon as it failed, rather than waiting for all of the tests to complete then having it list out all of the failures.

How can I tell phpunit to do this?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Add the `stopOnFailure="true"` attribute to your `phpunit.xml` root element.

You can also use it in the CLI: `phpunit --stop-on-failure`

Info from manual and some others that are maybe useful for you:

- stopOnError - "Stop execution upon first error."
- stopOnFailure - "Stop execution upon first error or failure."
- stopOnIncomplete - "Stop execution upon first incomplete test."

More info at: [PHPunit manual](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/11.1/textui.html)

Comment: At least as of PHPUnit 11, the "stopOnFailure" doesn't stop on errors anymore. A combination of "--stop-on-error" and "--stop-on-failure" does the trick. Docs: https://docs.phpunit.de/en/11.0/textui.html#automatically-stop-when

Comment: @SjorsOttjes `--stop-on-failure` isn't working for me any more at all? PHPUnit 10.5.13. `--stop-on-defect` works however.